# placeholder text in category form label

Tags: forms, text

Is there a way to put a placeholder text in the category form label? Right now the label is empty and has a dropdown menu filled with categories. I want to make a dummy placeholder text which will be something to : CHOOSE THE CATEGORY!

```
<option value="<option value="<?php wp_dropdown_categories('exclude=34, selected=0'); ?>    
</option>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as an argument:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=CHOOSE THE CATEGORY!' ); ?>
```

Reference: [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if I understand your question right. Do you need the parameter `'show_option_none'` or something else?

Comment: I have a custom form for users to submit articles. They need to choose the category. I need the first option to be sort of dummy text and not blank.